# How to add text description heading for the confusion matrix table

Tags: tables, formatting

I am trying to create a table known as the Confusion matrix in machine learning which should look like this:

[image: desired table].

However, I am unable to code for the writings cars, trees etc and the table is getting distorted. The code is below

```
\documentclass[%
 aip,
 jmp,%
 amsmath,amssymb,
preprint,%reprint,
dvipsnames%
%author-year,%
%author-numerical,%
]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}% Enable numbering of text and display math
\linenumbers\relax % Commence numbering lines
\usepackage{hyperref}
 \usepackage{color}
     \usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

 \begin{table*}
\caption{Confusion Matrix.} % title of
\centering % used for centering table
\begin{tabular}{l|l|c|c|c|c|c}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Predicted}\\
\cline{3-6}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{}& 0 &  1 &2 &  3 &    \\
 & \small{(cars)}  & \small{(cars+human)} & (trees) &  (animal)  &\multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
\cline{2-6}
\multirow{}{}{Actual}& 0  &   &  & & \\
\cline{2-6}
& 1   &  &   & &\\
\cline{2-6}
&   2 &   & &  & \\
\cline{2-6}
&   3 &   &  &  &   \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c} {} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
\end{tabular}
\label{Table1}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

The above code generates this table instead:

[image: incorrect]

Please help in getting the correct table so that the headings have a text description in a new line. Thank you.

---

UPDATE: Following the answer given by Andrew, I have implemented the code. There are two things to modify: (a) how to get rid of the vertical line on the top left corner? I have been able to get rid of the horizontal line. Since that cell is empty, there should be no lines there. (b) after filling in the values, there are a lot of empty spaces. How to make the table look visually appealing so that the spaces get adjusted themselves?

```
 \begin{table*}
    \caption{Confusion Matrix.} % title of
    \centering % used for centering table
      \begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}{l@{\quad}|X|X|X|X|X|}
        \multicolumn1l{}&\multicolumn{5}{c}{\sffamily Predicted}\\\cline{3-6}
        &  & \textsf{0}&\textsf{1} &\textsf{2}&\textsf{3} \\
        &  & \textsf{(cars)} &\textsf{(cars+humans)} & \textsf{(trees)} & \textsf{(human)} \\\cline{2-6}
        \multirow{8}{*}{\sffamily \rotatebox{90}{Actual}}
        & \textsf{0}& 100&0 & 0&0 \\
        &   & & & &\\  \cline{2-6}
        & \textsf{1}&0 &100 & 0& 0\\
        &   & & & & \\  \cline{2-6}
        & \textsf{2}&0 &0 & 100&0 \\
        &   & & & & \\  \cline{2-6}
        & \textsf{3}&0 &0 & 0& 100\\
        &   & & & & \\  \cline{2-6}
      \end{tabularx}
    \label{Table1}
\end{table*}
```

Which gives the following output:

[image: new]

Comment: What does "spaces get adjusted themselves" mean exactly? Do you want equal column widths for all columns or should columns with wider contents be wider than columns with narrower contenst? What about the height of the table rows?

Comment: `\multicolumn1l{}`is not ideal. Probably you wanted to use `\multicolumn{1}{l}{}` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the following suits your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass[%
 aip,
 jmp,%
 amsmath,amssymb,
preprint,%reprint,
dvipsnames%
%author-year,%
%author-numerical,%
]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}% Enable numbering of text and display math
\linenumbers\relax % Commence numbering lines
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
    \caption{Confusion Matrix.} % title of
    \centering % used for centering table
      \begin{tabular}{l@{\quad}|l|*{4}{wc{2.75cm}|}}
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{} &   \multicolumn{4}{c}{Predicted}              \\  \cline{3-6}
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &   & 0      & 1            & 2       & 3       \\
        \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &   & (cars) &(cars+humans) & (trees) & (human) \\  \cline{2-6}
        \multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Actual}}
                             & 0 & 100    & 0            & 0       & 0       \\ \cline{2-6}
                             & 1 & 0      & 100          & 0       & 0       \\ \cline{2-6}
                             & 2 & 0      & 0            & 100     & 0       \\ \cline{2-6}
                             & 3 & 0      & 0            & 0       & 100     \\ \cline{2-6}
      \end{tabular}
    \label{Table1}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is what you can do with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 3pt}

\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{2mm}

 \begin{table*}
\caption{Confusion Matrix.}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{c*{4}{wc{2cm}}}[first-row,first-col,hvlines]
  & & \Block{1-4}{Predicted}\\
  & & \Block{}{0 \\ (cars)} 
    & \Block{}{1 \\ (cars+humans)} 
    & \Block{}{2 \\ (trees)}
    & \Block{}{3 \\ (human)} \\
\Block{4-1}{\rotate Actual}
  & 0 \\
  & 1 \\
  & 2 \\
  & 3 \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\label{Table1}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

- In `{NiceTabular}`, you have keys `first-row` and `first-col`. The, the key `hvlines` will draw all the rules excepted in the first row and in the first column.
- You can merge cells with `\Block`, both horizontally and vertically.

[image: Output of the above code]

If you don't want any border for the upper-left cell, you can use the key `corners` to specify corners where the rules won't be drawn (the corners are computed automatically).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 3pt}

\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{2mm}

 \begin{table*}
\caption{Confusion Matrix.}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{c*{4}{wc{2cm}}}[first-row,first-col,hvlines,corners=NW]
  & & \Block{1-4}{Predicted}\\
  & & \Block{}{0 \\ (cars)} 
    & \Block{}{1 \\ (cars+humans)} 
    & \Block{}{2 \\ (trees)}
    & \Block{}{3 \\ (human)} \\
\Block{4-1}{\rotate Actual}
  & 0 \\
  & 1 \\
  & 2 \\
  & 3 \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\label{Table1}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]

Answer (score 3):

For the reasons explained in the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs)  manual, I am not a big fan of having vertical and horizontal rules in tables, but if this is what you want then here is one way to do this.

[image]

A few remarks:

- you should load the [hyperref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package last
- I have switched to using a `tabularx` environment, of width `0.8\textwidth`, as this way you can use an `X`-column type to space out columns of the same width
- The left hand column of the matrix is there only for the word `Actual`, which is typeset using `\multirow` and `\rotatebox` from the [graphicx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) package to rotate the word `Actual`
- I do not know what the entries of this matrix look like, but based the MWE I have assumed that it is reasonable to place them in a second row below the row heading in column 2. Depending on what actually goes in these table cells you might instead, want to use `\multirow`.
- the row and column headings are typeset using `\sffamily`

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[%
 aip,
 jmp,%
 amsmath,amssymb,
preprint,%reprint,
dvipsnames%
%author-year,%
%author-numerical,%
]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{tabularx}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}% Enable numbering of text and display math
\linenumbers\relax % Commence numbering lines
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

 \begin{table*}
    \caption{Confusion Matrix.} % title of
    \centering % used for centering table
      \begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}{l@{\quad}*5{|X}|}
        \multicolumn1l{}&\multicolumn{5}{c}{\sffamily Predicted}\\\cline{2-6}
        & & \textsf{0}&\textsf{1} &\textsf{2}&\textsf{3} \\
        & & \textsf{(cars)} &\textsf{(cars+humans)} & \textsf{(trees)} & \textsf{(human)} \\\cline{2-6}
        \multirow{8}{*}{\sffamily \rotatebox{90}{Actual}}
        & \textsf{0}& & & & \\
        &   & & & & \\  \cline{2-6}
        & \textsf{1}& & & & \\
        &   & & & & \\  \cline{2-6}
        & \textsf{2}& & & & \\
        &   & & & & \\  \cline{2-6}
        & \textsf{3}& & & & \\
        &   & & & & \\  \cline{2-6}
      \end{tabularx}
    \label{Table1}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but there is slight difference in the table that you have generated. The confusion matrix must have the top left cell empty like the the one I showed in the first picture. Your code has zero label on top left. That needs to be shifted by one step to the right so that the top left cell is blank. Could you please modify your code if possible? Lastly, what does the command `{l@{\quad}*4{|X}|}` stand for? Can the same code be applied for extending the table to have more than 4 columns and rows?

Comment: @Sm1 Fixed. Yes, this works for more columns. You can use `@{...}` in the tabular specifications to add code in between the columns, so `@{\quad}` inserts a quad-space between columns 1 and 2, which puts a little bit of space between the word `Actual` and the table.  Using `*` is a useful abbreviation for repeating a column specification: `*4{|X}` is the same as repeating `|X` four times. So `{l@{\quad}*4{|X}|}` is the same as `l@{\quad}|X|X|X|X|`.

Comment: Finally, the `X` is an eXpandable column. The four `X`'s in the table specification all expand to columns to the same width that are as large as possible for given the width of the table, which is set to `0.8\textwidth` or 80% of the page width.

Comment: Thank you again for the explanation and the updates. There are two things which are not quite right when I implemented your answer and filled in with the numbers. Can you please take a look at the updated question? Basically, I want to get rid of the lines around the empty cell on the top left corner and reduce the space after the numbers are filled in.